# C language how can i write Java like multi thread for a specific task? Can it be done as objective-c?

Tags: java, c, linux, multithreading

How do we create multi thread or process? For cross platform using C language? And close the thread when it requires. Write once and deploy platforms such as Linux/Windows/Mac/Android/MeeGo.

**Example in java:** runnable = new Mytest(); thread = new Thread(runnable);

```
Step 1:
    runnable = new Mytest();
    thread = new Thread(runnable);

Step 2:

public class Mytest implements Runnable
{
  private static volatile boolean running = true
  public void run()
  {
    while(running) 
    { // do stuff }
  }
  public void start() { running = true; }
  public void stop()  { running = false;}
}
```

**Follow up:**

Step 1: vim omp_hello.c ( https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/exercise.html )

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int nthreads, tid;
  #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
  {

    /* Obtain thread number */
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

    /* Only master thread does this */
    if (tid == 0) 
    {
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }

  }  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

}
```

Step 2: $ gcc -fopenmp omp_hello.c -o hello

Step 3: $ setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 4

Step 4: $ ./hello

```
Hello World from thread = 0 
Number of threads = 4
Hello World from thread = 3
Hello World from thread = 1
Hello World from thread = 2
```

Done. it Works!

Comment: AFAIK, you can't run C on Android...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of threading in the C language.  Most platforms have their own specific libraries or API for threading (obviously some platforms can't support threading at all).

However, 3rd-party libraries such as [OpenMP](http://openmp.org) exist, which offer platform-independent threading, to an extent.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you will want to use the [Boost Thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html) - it's cross-platform, easy to use, and really solid. I don't know of a similar library for C.

Threads are purely a library issue in C and C++, specifically because they're implemented differently on every platform.

Comment: Thanks. But writing in C++ is for me better to do it with D language. I just need native-C threading.

Answer (score 0):

With C language you can use [pthread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) but for what concerning croossplatform developing, it's up to you resolving specific issue for every operating system.

Comment: Thanks, not cross platform alas :(

Answer (score 0):

wxWidget is multiplatform(C++ on Linux/Windows/Mac) and has it's special thread class : wxThread (multiplatform). GUI is also multiplatform by the way.
I don't see how you can deploy once using different languages (android is Java and you want c++?)

Comment: Anything for C++, i prefer to use D language.